# ¿Cómo cambiar un input tipo password a un input tipo text con un checkbox en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Mi código esta así:

```js
function hideOrShowPassword() {
  var password1, password2, check;

  password1 = document.getElementById("password1");
  password2 = document.getElementById("password2");
  check = document.getElementById("ver");

  if (check.checked == true) // Si la checkbox de mostrar contraseña está activada
  {
    password1.type = "text";
    password2.type = "text";
  } else // Si no está activada 
  {
    password1.type = "password";
    password2.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="../validar.js"></script>

<input class="input-100" type="password" id="password1" name="password1" maxlength="39" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña " />
<br>
<input class="input-100" type="password" id="password2" name="password2" maxlength="39" placeholder="Verifica tu contraseña " />
<small>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ver" class="ver" onChange="hideOrShowPassword()" />
    <label class="text">Mostrar contraseña</label>
</small>
```

Y quiero que al habilitar el checkbox, se cambie el `type` de los inputs a `text`.

Comment: ¿En qué navegador y qué versión no te funciona? ¿Algún error en consola?

Comment: uso google chrome

Comment: Se puede verificar que funciona ejecutando tu código en la pregunta. El error está en algún otro lado. ¿Algún error en consola?

Comment: ya me sirvio ... aunque no sirve todo mi código queria validar un formulario pero no me sirve el código

Comment: No entiendo. ¿qué es lo que "no sirve"? Tu pregunta no es sobre validación, sino sobre mostrar o no el texto de un input.

Comment: si ya sirvió gracias

Comment: Ok. Votando por cerrar como "no reproducible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que tienes funciona:

```js
function hideOrShowPassword(){
  var password1,password2,check;

  password1=document.getElementById("password1");
  password2=document.getElementById("password2");
  check=document.getElementById("ver");

  if(check.checked==true) // Si la checkbox de mostrar contraseña está activada
  {
      password1.type = "text";
      password2.type = "text";
  }
  else // Si no está activada
  {
      password1.type = "password";
      password2.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="input-100" type="password"id="password1" name="password1" maxlength="39"  placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña " />
<br>
<input class="input-100" type="password"id="password2" name="password2" maxlength="39"  placeholder="Verifica tu contraseña " />
<small>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ver" class="ver" onChange="hideOrShowPassword()" />
    <label class="text">Mostrar contraseña</label>
</small>
```

Comment: a mi no me sirve ... no se porque

Comment: Puede a que se deba que tienes tu archivo javascript en otro lado, en tu linea `<script src="../validar.js"></script>` puede que tu archivo javascript este donde mismo que tu archivo html y no tendrías que retroceder en la carpeta para encontrarlo seria así: `<script src="validar.js"></script>`.

Comment: mmm la verdad si está al mismo nivel

Comment: te comparto el código?

Comment: Si esta al mimo nivel solo ocupas ajustar la linea donde lo llamas `<script src="validar.js"></script>` y ver que el nombre este bien escrito.

Comment: lo siento quería decir que no estaba al mismo nivel jeje estoy un poco distraido porque ya puse la ruta exacta pero no me ejecuta la función y siento que es porque algo tengo mal en mi código